# Value Object persisting via Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I saw this sample [here](http://christianarg.wordpress.com/2010/09/10/c-net-immutable-properties-for-entity-framework-serializable-classes-etc/) , here is this suggested way to make vaueobject in DDD , take a look at this

```
public class SubCategory : ValueObjectBase
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int NumberOfPosts { get; private set; }

    public SubCategory()
    {
    }

    public SubCategory(string name, int numberOfPost)
    {
        Name = name;
        NumberOfPosts = numberOfPost;
    }
}
```

in my code , I'm using ValueObjectBase that don't let me to have any Id , every table in Entity framework mapping should have an Id to make a table in Database , How can I map this valueObject ann kinda imutable class ???

my mapping calss is like this :

```
public class SubCategoryMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<SubCategory>
{
    public SubCategoryMapping()
    {
        ToTable("SubCategory");
        // Id ????
        Property(sc => sc.Name);
        Property(sc => sc.NumberOfPosts);
    }
}
```

Comment: Making a value object aggregate root makes no sense at all. If you want a dedicated table for it you should give it an id. There is no workaround.

Comment: oh really sorry , I didn't notice about , you are right , now in this case SubCategory is actually a related to Category , and I wanna to make it immutable now , How can I persist it ??